# How to delete delimeters between entry sets in gost-numeric?

Tags: biblatex, xetex, biber

I have a set of @online resources that contains title and URL. I need to delete these "dot with dash" symbols before every entry. I try to add `\renewcommand*{\entrysetpunct}{\par\vspace{\bibitemsep}}` in preamble, but i only add pars between entries.
Example code:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black,
    breaklinks=true
}
\urlstyle{same} 

\usepackage[
citestyle=gost-numeric,
style=gost-numeric, 
backend=biber,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{main.bib}
@online{libreoffice,
title={LibreOffice license},
url={https://www.libreoffice.org/about-us/licenses}
}
@online{thunderbird,
title={Thunderbird official site},
url={https://www.thunderbird.net/}
}
@online{sites-name,
title={Infomation about software}
}
@set{sites,
entryset={sites-name, libreoffice, thunderbird}
}
\end{filecontents}

\renewcommand*{\entrysetpunct}{\par\vspace{\bibitemsep}}
\addbibresource{main.bib}

\begin{document}
Thunderbird\cite{sites}

LibreOffice\cite{sites}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dash is caused by the `blockpunct` option, which by default is `emdash`. This is documented in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-gost/doc/biblatex-gost.pdf) in section 5.1. Новые опции и значения опций on page 18. You can set it to space instead.

I'm not sure if you actually want each item of the entryset on a new line or not - removing the line you added leads to the following:

```
\usepackage[
citestyle=gost-numeric,
style=gost-numeric,
blockpunct=space,   %%% set blockpunct to space
backend=biber,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{main.bib}
...
\end{filecontents}

% don't change the entry set punctuation
%\renewcommand*{\entrysetpunct}{\par\vspace{\bibitemsep}}
```

[image]

If you do want every entry on a new line then you can redefine `\entrysetpunct` to be `\par` followed by `\nopunct` to remove the dot. The horizontal spacing is a bit off in that case so you can add some negative thinspaces `\!` at the end. Note that there is probably a better way to align this properly using some separation macro but I'm not sure what to use there.

```
\renewcommand*{\entrysetpunct}{\par\nopunct\!\!}
```

[image]

Comment: Can i set blockpunct only on certain fields? I mean i need to use emdash as blockpunct but i need to disable it between entrysets

Comment: I use only 2 fields: author and url, so i can do i want with little robust way:
`\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{--- URL: #1}`

Comment: How i can set spacing if i use `\sloppy` before `\printbibliography`?